# Masking layer with ConvLSTM2D Keras

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, masking

I am trying to use the Masking layer with `ConvLSTM2D` in keras. However, I keep gettin the error:

> ValueError: Shape must be rank 4 but is rank 2 for 'conv_lst_m2d_1/while/Tile' (op: 'Tile') with input shapes: [?,128,128,1], [2].

My input shape is `(None, 128, 128, 1)`

Comment: In order to use `ConvLSTM2D` in `keras` your input should have shape `(number_of_examples, timesteps, width, height, channels)` - so this is causing your mismatch.

Comment: This is my input shape: Input(shape=(78, 5, 128, 128, 3)). Still i get the same error